# 3D Engine with movie texture for iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios, 3d, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Is there any high level 3D engine capable of displaying movie texture on both iOS and Android?

This would be for a project close to a virtual museum with video playing on some walls. The engine would also be able to import 3D model from 3DS Max.

I checked major 3D engines but did not find the ideal one. Unity3D for instance does not support movie texture.

I am wondering if I can avoid coding low level OpenGL code on each platform.

Answer (score 0):

Unity does not support movie textures on mobile out of the box, but this Mobile Movie Texture plugin works quite well:

http://u3d.as/content/defiant-development-pty-ltd/mobile-movie-texture/2w1

p.s. I think it requires Unity Pro

Answer (score -1):

Unity3D supports [movie textures](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MovieTexture.html).  Update: only for desktop, it seems.

An alternative that does appear to work is [Bink](http://www.radgametools.com/bnkmain.htm) from Rad Game Tools.  This is just a (proprietary) video decoder library though that you'll most probably have to incorporate into your own engine (I believe I'm right in saying that you can specify the memory buffer the video is rendered to, so once you have the frame you can do whatever you like with it).

Comment: Please, take a closer look at the documentation because it actually says "Movie Textures are not supported on iOS" and "Movie Textures are not supported on Android". It seems it works only on Desktop. Even on Unity3D Pro.

Comment: Ah right.  My mistake.  Annoyingly, it doesn't mention that in the scripting reference.  I'll provide an alternative in my original answer.  :)